# Magento Stack Trace - Feed failed to load, got response code 404

Tags: frontend-error

We have just moved our installation of Magento over to a new host. Everything has gone over ok that I can see. I can access and login to the back-end fine - no problems there at all, but whenever I access a front-end page - I'm getting a Trace stack like this:

```
Feed failed to load, got response code 404

Trace:
/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/rampco/template/page/3columns.phtml(62): Zend_Feed_Abstract->__construct
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/httpdocs/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

I've spent so long now looking for any clue as to what may be causing this, but the "Feed failed to load, got response code 404" seems to be the rarest error in the history of Magento!

Any light that anyone can shed on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: i have a similar problem, can you please explain how you resolved the problem? Thanks Philip.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you try to consume a feed in your root template. This feed is not available (404), the Zend library [throws an exception accordingly](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Feed/Abstract.php#L86).

As this is done in your custom theme `default/rampco`, the error is limited to your installation (rare, as you say).

The feed URI is truncated in your stack trace. So there are actually two things to be done:

1. Check the full feed URI and, if in your area, re-establish availability.
2. Catch the exception before it hits the UI.

Comment: Thanks so much mam08ixo. You pointed me in the right direction and have the site up and running again.

All the best,
Vortex

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark this answer accepted then.